# node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080 throw err; ^ Error: Cannot find module'-e'Require stack: - /usr/local/lib/node_modules/migrate/bin/migrate-up

Tags: node.js, docker, node-modules, migrate

When I try to run the an API with `sudo make migrate` this happens

```
`node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1080
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '-e'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/migrate/bin/migrate-up
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/migrate/bin/migrate-up:63:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/migrate/bin/migrate-up' ]
}

Node.js v18.17.0
make[1]: *** [migrate] Error 1
make: *** [setup] Error 2`
```

I tried to change the node version and download the migrate module, but it didn't work